# popup box is not going when I click on submit button using ajax in ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am creating a popup box for reset password and below is the button where I click to open popup box:

```
<table align="center" width="80%">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <div class="button">
                            <a id="ResetPass" class="buttonSearch">Open</a>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
</table>
```

below is the javascript function that find button and use to open popup box:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var el=document.getElementById("ResetPass");
        el.onclick = show_dialog2;
        function show_dialog2() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
        }
    </script>
```

Below is the div that have a form and controls on it:

```
<div id="dialog" style="visibility:hidden" title="Reset Password" type="hidden">
                <%= form_tag({ controller: "settings", action: "reset_password"}, remote: "true" ) do |f| %>
                    <table style="text-align:center; vertical-align:top;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>

                                    <p><%= label_tag(:name, "Name") %>
                                    <%= text_field_tag(:name) %></p>


                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <%= text_field_tag( :newpassword, :placeholder => "New Password", :style => "text-align: center; BackColor:#e5e5e5; Width: 150px; ForeColor: Gray; Font-Size: Large;") %>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <%= text_field_tag( :reenterpassword, :placeholder => "Re-enter Password", :style => "text-align: center; BackColor: #e5e5e5; Width: 150px; ForeColor: Gray; Font-Size: Large;") %>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr> 
                    </table>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <%= submit_tag 'Submit', :id => "_button" %>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                <% end %>
</div>
```

But the problem is that when I enter values in the textboxes and click on submit button the popup box is not going , kindly help me waiting for your reply.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to add the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // '_button' is the Id of your submit button
    $("#_button").click(function() {            
      $(this).closest("form").submit();
      $("#dialog").dialog("close");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: but its not submitting the popup box controls values into controllers page.

Comment: try to add `$(this).closest("form").submit();` see my updated code

Answer (score 1):

Are you using bootstrap 3 for the popup? If it it so, then u have to add the action to close the modal when the response has get successful result.

```
$('#dialog').modal('hide');
```

Hope it helps

Comment: JQuery? Try this

    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "close" );